# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've written this script to make a TCPIP request to my machine, this works fine.

When I get `status = 0` in the switch (0 = card reader not ready) I wrote the code so that an interval after 10 seconds "presses" again the "#print_card" button so that it tries the request again.

Everything works fine but when I press the button again with `$('#print_card').trigger("click");` I get the famous error:

***Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while using jQuery*** and the console gives this to the `bootstrap.min.js:6` file (which is the original Bootstrap file).

I tried `$('#print_card').click();` and nothing changes...

This is my code. If I remove line #439 `$('#print_card').trigger("click");` I don't get the error...:

```
  var interval;
  var status_timer;
  function attendi_e_riprova(txt){
    var sec = 10;

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(sec != 1){
        sec--;
        if(sec == 1){
          sec_word = 'secondo';
        }else{
          sec_word = 'secondi';
        }
        $('#card-modal-body').html('<p>'+txt+'</p>');
      }else{
        clearInterval(interval);

        //THIS IS THE TRIGGER <-----------------------------------
        $('#print_card').trigger("click");
        //THIS IS THE TRIGGER <-----------------------------------

        return false;
      }
    }, 1000);

    $('.close').click(function(){
      clearInterval(interval);
      clearInterval(status_timer);         
    }); 

  }

  var codemaster = '1';
  var chain = 1;
  var shop = 1;

  function scriviCard(){
    //Another function
  }


  $('#print_card').click(function(){
    $('#card-modal-body').html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Ricerca del lettore e card, attendere&hellip;</p>');

    var req = '"CWD2";"';

    $.post(base_url()+'config/RichiestaTCPIP', {array:req}, function(status){
      if(status == 'err'){
        console.error('Errore: controller file config.php funzione di linea #117');
      }else{
        console.log('Status: '+status)

        switch(status){
          case '0':
            attendi_e_riprova('<i class="fa fa-ban text-danger"></i> Lettore NON disponibile. Assicurarsi che sia collegato.');
          break;
          case '1':
            attendi_e_riprova('Lettore vuoto. Inserire una card vergine per poterla scrivere.');
          break;
          case '4':
            attendi_e_riprova('<i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> Card trovata. In attesa di riconoscimento...');
          break;
          case '5':
            attendi_e_riprova('<i class="fa fa-ban text-danger"></i> Card in scrittura. Attendere completamento.');
          break;
          default:
            //Nuova richiesta per la creazione card (per status 2 o 3)
            scriviCard();
            //console.log(status)
          break;
        }
      }         
    })

  })
```

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before the bootstrap file? Are you waiting the DOM is loaded before using jQuery in your code?

Comment: *"I've written this script to make a TCPIP request to my machine..."* Not *nearly* that low-level. :-) You're asking the browser to make an HTTP request for you.

Comment: You are missing a few `;` on a few places, like after the `clearInterval(t); })` for example

Comment: Try using `$('#print_card').click();`

Comment: @MarcoCI jQuery loads first, second the bootstrap and third this code which is not in an external file but in the page itself.

Comment: @urbz :D Yes I meant the post request to the `config/RichiestaTCPIP` page is actually making a TCPIP request thru a HTTP socket.

Comment: @shaunakde that was my first trial and the same result appears.

Comment: @urbz Tku, I placed all the missing ; but nothing is changing. The weird thing ***should*** be with the click() event as if I remove it I don't get the error.

Comment: @Mr.Web - Could it be that your `return: false;`, taken in by accident, does not trigger the click?

Comment: @urbz Tku, no, the function is triggering, I may have missed to specify it, but the action is working, I just get that error... I I remove return true (or false, tried as well) nothing changes.

Comment: @Mr.Web - Ok.. Hmm... I am just concerned since you have a `.trigger()` click inside a big `.click()` function.. maybe instead of trigger do `$('#print_card').live("click");` instead? I am primarily guessing here.. :-/

Comment: Could you try using the non-minified bootstrap.js file and see at which line the error occurs there?

Comment: @Mr.Web, have you tried `this.$self.trigger()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try defining your function in a variable before the trigger command! something like this:

```
window.clickFunction=function(
    $('#card-modal-body').html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Ricerca del lettore e card, attendere&hellip;</p>');

var req = '"CWD2";"';

$.post(base_url()+'config/RichiestaTCPIP', {array:req}, function(status){
  if(status == 'err'){
    console.error('Errore: controller file config.php funzione di linea #117');
  }else{
    console.log('Status: '+status)

    switch(status){
      case '0':
        attendi_e_riprova('<i class="fa fa-ban text-danger"></i> Lettore NON disponibile. Assicurarsi che sia collegato.');
      break;
      case '1':
        attendi_e_riprova('Lettore vuoto. Inserire una card vergine per poterla scrivere.');
      break;
      case '4':
        attendi_e_riprova('<i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> Card trovata. In attesa di riconoscimento...');
      break;
      case '5':
        attendi_e_riprova('<i class="fa fa-ban text-danger"></i> Card in scrittura. Attendere completamento.');
      break;
      default:
        //Nuova richiesta per la creazione card (per status 2 o 3)
        scriviCard();
        //console.log(status)
      break;
    }
  }});
```

and then when you want to call it use it like this:

```
$('#print_card').click(window.clickFunction);
```

or

```
window.clickFunction.trigger();
```

NOTE: you have to define the variable as a global variable and MUST be defined before the trigger or click line!

let me know how it goes.

Comment: OK, that worked! I did it this way: `window.clickFunction=function{...}` and instead of `window.clickFunction.trigger();` I just placed a normal javascript `clickFunction();`